# Interpreting visual studio profiler, is this subtraction slow? Can I make all this any faster?

Tags: c++, performance, profiling

I'm using the Visual Studio profiler for the first time and I'm trying to interpret the results. Looking at the percentages on the left, I found this subtraction's time cost a bit strange:

[image]

Other parts of the code contain more complex expressions, like:

[image]

Even a simple multiplication seems way faster than the subtraction :

[image]

Other multiplications take way longer and I really don't get why, like this :

[image]

So, I guess my question is if there is anything weird going on here.

Complex expressions take longer than that subtraction and some expressions take way longer than similar other ones. I run the profiler several times and the distribution of the percentages is always like this. Am I just interpreting this wrong?

**Update:**

I was asked to give the profile for the whole function so here it is, even though it's a bit big. I ran the function inside a  for loop for 1 minute and got 50k samples. The function contains a double loop. I include the text first for ease, followed by the pictures of profiling. Note that the code in text is a bit updated.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CONTOUR_POINTS; i++) {

    vec4 contourPointV(contour3DPoints[i], 1);
    float phi = angles[i];

    float xW = pose[0][0] * contourPointV.x + pose[1][0] * contourPointV.y + contourPointV.z * pose[2][0] + pose[3][0];
    float yW = pose[0][1] * contourPointV.x + pose[1][1] * contourPointV.y + contourPointV.z * pose[2][1] + pose[3][1];
    float zW = pose[0][2] * contourPointV.x + pose[1][2] * contourPointV.y + contourPointV.z * pose[2][2] + pose[3][2];

    float x = -G_FU_STRICT * xW / zW;
    float y = -G_FV_STRICT * yW / zW;
    x = (x + 1) * G_WIDTHo2;
    y = (y + 1) * G_HEIGHTo2;
    y = G_HEIGHT - y;



    phi -= extraTheta;
    if (phi < 0)phi += CV_PI2;
    int indexForTable = phi * oneKoverPI;
    //vec2 ray(cos(phi), sin(phi));
    vec2 ray(cos_pre[indexForTable], sin_pre[indexForTable]);
    vec2 ray2(-ray.x, -ray.y);
    float outerStepX = ray.x * step;
    float outerStepY = ray.y * step;
    cv::Point2f outerPoint(x + outerStepX, y + outerStepY);
    cv::Point2f innerPoint(x - outerStepX, y - outerStepY);
    cv::Point2f contourPointCV(x, y);
    cv::Point2f contourPointCVcopy(x, y);

    bool cut = false;
    if (!isInView(outerPoint.x, outerPoint.y) || !isInView(innerPoint.x, innerPoint.y)) {
        cut = true;
    }
    bool outside2 = true; bool outside1 = true;

    if (cut) {
        outside2 = myClipLine(contourPointCV.x, contourPointCV.y, outerPoint.x, outerPoint.y, G_WIDTH - 1, G_HEIGHT - 1);
        outside1 = myClipLine(contourPointCVcopy.x, contourPointCVcopy.y, innerPoint.x, innerPoint.y, G_WIDTH - 1, G_HEIGHT - 1);
    }


    myIterator innerRayMine(contourPointCVcopy, innerPoint);
    myIterator outerRayMine(contourPointCV, outerPoint);

    if (!outside1) {
        innerRayMine.end = true;
        innerRayMine.prob = true;
    }
    if (!outside2) {
        outerRayMine.end = true;
        innerRayMine.prob = true;
    }



    vec2 normal = -ray;
    float dfdxTerm = -normal.x;
    float dfdyTerm = normal.y;
    vec3 point3D = vec3(xW, yW, zW);
    cv::Point contourPoint((int)x, (int)y);



    float Xc = point3D.x; float Xc2 = Xc * Xc; float Yc = point3D.y; float Yc2 = Yc * Yc; float Zc = point3D.z; float Zc2 = Zc * Zc;
    float XcYc = Xc * Yc; float dfdxFu = dfdxTerm * G_FU; float dfdyFv = dfdyTerm * G_FU; float overZc2 = 1 / Zc2; float overZc = 1 / Zc;
    pixelJacobi[0] = (dfdyFv * (Yc2 + Zc2) + dfdxFu * XcYc) * overZc2;
    pixelJacobi[1] = (-dfdxFu * (Xc2 + Zc2) - dfdyFv * XcYc) * overZc2;
    pixelJacobi[2] = (-dfdyFv * Xc + dfdxFu * Yc) * overZc;
    pixelJacobi[3] = -dfdxFu * overZc;
    pixelJacobi[4] = -dfdyFv * overZc;
    pixelJacobi[5] = (dfdyFv * Yc + dfdxFu * Xc) * overZc2;


    float commonFirstTermsSum = 0;
    float commonFirstTermsSquaredSum = 0;

    int test = 0;
    while (!innerRayMine.end) {

        test++;
        cv::Point xy = innerRayMine.pos(); innerRayMine++;
        int x = xy.x;
        int y = xy.y;
        float dx = x - contourPoint.x;
        float dy = y - contourPoint.y;
        vec2 dxdy(dx, dy);

        float raw = -glm::dot(dxdy, normal);
        float heavisideTerm = heaviside_pre[(int)raw * 100 + 1000];
        float deltaTerm = delta_pre[(int)raw * 100 + 1000];


        const Vec3b rgb = ante[y * 640 + x];
        int red = rgb[0]; int green = rgb[1]; int blue = rgb[2];
        red = red >> 3; red = red << 10; green = green >> 3; green = green << 5; blue = blue >> 3;
        int colorIndex = red + green + blue;

        pF = pFPointer[colorIndex];
        pB = pBPointer[colorIndex];
        float denAsMul = 1 / (pF + pB + 0.000001);
        pF = pF * denAsMul;

        float pfMinusPb = 2 * pF - 1;
        float denominator = heavisideTerm * (pfMinusPb)+pB + 0.000001;
        float commonFirstTerm = -pfMinusPb / denominator * deltaTerm;

        commonFirstTermsSum += commonFirstTerm;
        commonFirstTermsSquaredSum += commonFirstTerm * commonFirstTerm;

    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Moar context required. Subtraction is usually quite cheap so we need to see what's going on around that subtraction to see, for example, how many times it's getting called relative to the rest of the code.

Comment: @user4581301 Sorry, as I said it's the first time I'm profiling and I'm not sure how much I needed to provide. All this is inside a specific function that takes up 50% of the profiling. The function is quite long and I let the profiler run for about a minute running the function in a large for loop. Since it is a very long function to include here in the question, what can I provide so people here can help?

Comment: We need the context of the function (so at least the chunk of code profiled, and the type of the related variables). How many times the function is executed? What are the compiler optimization flags (if any)? What is the target architecture/processor?

Comment: @JérômeRichard I will try and add more information when I get the profiler to work. It stopped working suddenly because of a common bug 
"There is no data in the current set of filters".

Comment: @JérômeRichard Regarding optimization I have just activated O2 in c/c++ optimization settings. As for architecture/processor, if I understand what you mean correctly, architecture is x64 and I'm using one core of an i5 10300h.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio profiles by sampling: it interrupts execution often and records the value of the instruction pointer; it then maps it to the source and calculates the frequency of hitting that line.

There are few issues with that: it's not always possible to figure out which line produced a specific assembly instruction in the optimized code.

One trick I use is to move the code of interest into a separate function and declare it with `__declspec(noinline)` .

In your example, are you sure the subtraction was performed as many times as multiplication? I would be more puzzled by the difference in subsequent multiplication (`0.39%` and `0.53%`)

**Update:**

I believe that the following lines:

```
float phi = angles[i];
```

and

```
phi -= extraTheta;
```

got moved together in assembly and the time spent getting `angles[i]` was added to that subtraction line.

Comment: This clarifies a few things. What will I earn by using declspec? I will try and get back with more details when I get profiling to to work again. It suddenly stopped working because of a common bug
"There is no data in the current set of filters".

Comment: Interesting. There is also an important factor on [modern processors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscalar_processor): instructions can be executed in parallel. As a result, some lines can be "slower" than other because they are latency bound and on the critical path. Thus the question is then: what metric visual studio use to select with instructions are "slower" than others. Besides this, I am a bit confused with the `sin`+`cos` calls: they are marked as only 50% slower than the subtraction while trigonometric functions are generally very expensive. It is only just a sampling issue?

Comment: @JohnKatsantas `noinline` instructs the compiler to NOT inline the function at the call site, so all hits in that function can be trusted.

Comment: @VladFeinstein Subtraction is in the first loop while some multiplications are in the nested loop. I updated the question with most of the function, you can check.

Comment: @JohnKatsantasplease see my update

Comment: @VladFeinstein That definitely makes sense. I would check it if could but it's most likely the case. Even though you have answered the question, if you see anything that could somehow be improved, please let me know.

Comment: @JohnKatsantas it is hard to read code from pictures. Could you please post it as text?

Comment: @VladFeinstein Sure, I added the main part just now. I doubt there is much to be done though, it's mostly calculations.

Comment: @JohnKatsantas you ARE using those `commonFirstTermsSum` and `commonFirstTermsSquaredSum`, right? Because your sample code calculates them and throws away...